# I don't understand how synchronization works in my code

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

I have a question regarding multythreading and specifically synchronization. I've created a Runnable that adds two numbers entered by the user, but their outputs are mixed up.

I've tried synchronizing on the method that the Runnable calls. This didn't work (I believe it has to do with the Threads being different objects thus not using the same instance of the method)... I then tried to synchronize on one of the objects but that also didn't give the desired result.

Could somebody please explain what is happening? See the code below:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Thread a = new Thread( new <CLASSNAME>, "Thread A"); 
    Thread b = new Thread( new <CLASSNAME>, "Thread B"); 

    synchronized (a) {
        a.start(); 
    }
    synchronized (a) {
        b.start(); 
    }
}
```

This gives a result like

```
Thread A: <INPUT PROMPT 1>
Thread B: <INPUT PROMPT 1>
Thread B: <INPUT PROMPT 2>
Thread A: <INPUT PROMPT 2>

Thread A: <OUTPUT>
Thread B: <OUTPUT>
```

I get that this problem could be solved using the join method, but I would also like to know why the synchronization failed. Does it have to do anything with the fact that I don't actually try to do something with `Thread a` in the synchronization of `Thread b` ?

Comment: `a.start()` will only trigger the new thread and immediately return. Therefore, the `synchronized(a) { ..; }` statement around it is meaningless, and won't affect how the `run()` method works.

Comment: To synchronize, you need lock on a common object. You can try creating a static variable and synchronize on it

Comment: What is the expected output here?

Comment: @Laurens: Explains us what behaviour are you trying to implement? Do you want that first one thread enters needed data, completes its work and then the other thread starts input? Or do you expect something other`?

Comment: @mentallurg that is indeed the intended behaviour. I was mainly puzzled why the above code didn't acomplish that, which was answered by 'that other guy'.

Comment: Please check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29883719/java-multithreading-threadsafe-counter, as it is very similar to what you seem to like to achieve.

Comment: Its sounds like you want one piece of code to execute and complete first, and then another piece of code. That's not what threads are for; threads are for running code at the same time. Luckily you don't need threads - just create the two runnables  and call them in sequence: `runnable1.run(); runnable2.run();`

Comment: What is the meaning of your title? There is no 'unused object' here.

Comment: You have a placeholder for `<CLASSNAME>`. Where is your runnable and how does it look like. Please post a minimal and reproducible example by looking at this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

I've added some comments to your code to explain:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Thread a = new Thread( new <CLASSNAME>, "Thread A");
        Thread b = new Thread( new <CLASSNAME>, "Thread B");

        // synchronize all threads call 'a.start()'
        // but in this case, only main thread call
        // so 'synchronized' is unnecessary
        synchronized (a) {
            a.start();
        }

        // synchronize all threads call 'b.start()'
        // but in this case, only main thread call
        // so 'synchronized' is unnecessary
        synchronized (a) {
            b.start();
        }
}
```

equals to:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Thread a = new Thread( new <CLASSNAME>, "Thread A");
        Thread b = new Thread( new <CLASSNAME>, "Thread B");

        a.start();
        b.start();
}
```

please read [this guide](https://www.baeldung.com/java-synchronized) to learn more about `Java Synchronization`